# How to create pages for Excel report without using Microsoft reference

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I have this method of creating an Excel spreedsheet with my data listed below.

```
List<ReportData> rd = ReportData.getReportData(startTime, endTime, lNumber, sNumber);
    DataTable dt = buildDataTable(rd);


    //we actually ahve to have a gridview to put into excel
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.DataBind();

    //flush everything from response to be sure we get a clean start
    Response.ClearContent();


    //now we create excel file
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserRpt.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(tw);

    //send xls as response

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

My question is how can make it create more pages and write the data to them without creating multiple reports for each individual thing? Example: Page one display the first gv, second page display the second gv and so on. When I add a new grid it does not create a new page it just puts everything back to back. I hope this makes sense I will be happy to try to clarify anything. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of libraries that will help you with this. Some require Office to be installed, others don't.

Maybe try 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelGenerator

or

http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Which one would you recommend?

Comment: Also this is in asp.net is that a problem?

Comment: I used closedxml once upon a time. Was pretty easy to get along with.

Comment: I saw where office interop is not supported in ASP is this the case with the following?

Comment: No it shouldn't be. You should be able to write the excel spreadsheet out to a stream and then output the content in a way that is similar to how you have done it above.

Comment: office interop is only relevant if you are relying on having MS Office installed on your machine (or where IIS is hosted).

ClosedXML doesn't rely on MS Office to build the files

Comment: I think I will try closedxml then.

Comment: Ok not totally sure how this works... I put in dll and I can't get XLWorkBook()?

Comment: My report can display over a 1000 rows... I can't go in and set all these values.

Answer (score 0):

I am working as Social Media Developer at Aspose and our [Aspose.Cells API](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx) can be used to implement your requirement with ease. Please see the following sample code in this regard which exports the data from 3 different gridviews to three different excel sheets:

```
//Create a new Workbook
Aspose.Cells.Workbook workbook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook();

//Add 2 more worksheets other than default worksheet
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
//Add a new worksheet
workbook.Worksheets.Add();
}

//Import data from gridviews to worksheets
workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells.ImportGridView(Gridview1, 0, 0, true, false, true);
workbook.Worksheets[1].Cells.ImportGridView(Gridview2, 0, 0, true, false, true);
workbook.Worksheets[2].Cells.ImportGridView(Gridview3, 0, 0, true, false, true);

//Save the worksheet
workbook.Save("C:\\Data\\Aspose.xls");
```